# My program lock when I start the timer and I'm not sure why

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have created 2 programs. Both use timers with interval set to 250 milliseconds.

The problem is that my first program doesn't lock then I run it, and the second locks with out giving me ability to click stop button. By saying locks I mean that program runs do it's job until I stop it from VS.

I don't understand why I can't stop my first program while the basic same way work for other program. Any ideas?

Program that locks:

```
    private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrInterval.Interval = (int)nudInterval.Value;
        tmrInterval.Start();
    }

    private void ScanPort(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(address, port, null, null);

            if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne((int)nudTimeout.Value, false)) txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + port + " is open." + Environment.NewLine);
            else txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + port + " is closed." + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrInterval.Stop();
    }

    private void tmrInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScanPort(IPAddress.Parse(txtIP.Text), currentPort);
        currentPort++;
        if (currentPort == nudTo.Value) tmrInterval.Stop();
    }
```

Program that doesn't lock:

```
    void tmrPingInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtTo.Text == string.Empty) Ping(IPAddress.Parse(ip2str(startIP)));
        else
        {
            if (currentIP >= endIP) tmrPingInterval.Stop();
            Ping(IPAddress.Parse(ip2str(currentIP)));
            currentIP++;
        }
    }

    private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFrom.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            txtFrom.Enabled = false;
            txtTo.Enabled = false;
            txtDisplay.Text = string.Empty;
            tsslPingCount.Text = string.Empty;
            count = 0;
            open = 0;
            closed = 0;
            tmrPingInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());

            try
            {
                startIP = str2ip(txtFrom.Text);
                if (txtTo.Text != string.Empty) endIP = str2ip(txtTo.Text);
                currentIP = startIP;
                tmrPingInterval.Start();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be in IP format: 100.100.100.100", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtFrom.Enabled = true;
                txtTo.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("IP field cannot be empty!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFrom.Enabled = true;
        txtTo.Enabled = true;
        tmrPingInterval.Stop();
    }

    private void Ping(IPAddress address)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        if (cbDontFragment.Checked) options.DontFragment = true;
        else options.DontFragment = false;
        string data = string.Empty;
        int dataCounter = 0;
        options.Ttl = (int)nudTTL.Value;

        for (int i = 0; i < nudData.Value; i++)
        {
            dataCounter++;
            if (dataCounter == 10) dataCounter = 0;
            data += dataCounter.ToString();
        }

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address, timeout, buffer, options);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtDisplay.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its probably because tmrPingInterval is threaded.

Comment: @Nix, I haven't use any threading in both of these examples.

Comment: tmrPingInterval is a Timer?  and what calls .Ping(  .  Please post more of your code.

Comment: @Nix, oh sorry I forgot to add this method. I have added this method to my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess here since we don't have enough information.  I am guessing that tmrInterval in a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  If that is the case, the what's happening is that when the timer ticks, it is handed as a windows message (the same way that mouse clicks, keystrokes, and everything else that make your application appear 'not frozen' are handled).

In the first application, you are doing something that takes substantial time- opening a TCP port, then waiting for a (presumably) large number of milliseconds until the TCP connects or doesnt, then almost immediately doing it again the next time that the timer ticks.  You are literally never giving the application a chance to respond to mouse clicks and keystrokes because the UI thread is busy trying to connect to some random ports somewhere.

In the second application, you are doing something relatively quick- just sending a ping somewhere.  what you will probably see in the second application is that your application will 'stutter'- become unresponsive for just a second or less while it pings whatever other machine you pointed it at.  It doesn't get hung because the UI thread isn't being given that much work to do.

To fix both of these, you should look into implementing a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  Timers (of any sort) are not generally considered a good way to spawn background tasks in .NET.

Comment: Seems like this explanation makes sense.

Comment: I haven't used background worker yet in any of my programs. How should I implement my program to use the worker? Do I initialize timer inside of background worker?

Comment: There are plenty of how-to articles on using backgroundworker out there.  For instance: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker.  You don't need a timer, just use a loop.  All you are using the timer for here is to increment the port number you are using.

Comment: Ah, so for loop will do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

About the first sample:

I guess from the context that the timer is a Windows.Forms.Timer. In the elapsed event you are executing a WaitOne(), and so effectively block the Messagepump.

As a possible solution, replace the Timer with a Threading.Timer to decouple the I/O from the main Thread.

Comment: Yes, I know. That part has to be moved or synced.

Comment: I know that, but I'm guessing the OP doesn't.  Just may want to expound on how to do that, to head off the inevitable "Control accessed from a thread other than the UI thread" question.